# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, datatable

Error is: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Scenario: I have a desktop application which loads XML Files and display the data in Grid. Now, I want to insert another file and want to append the data in both files. But, when I try to merge the data (I mean add the rows to DataTable which has rows of perviously opened file)...I am getting this error.

```
if (strPreviousFile != "")   
{  
  dgvBooksDetails.DataSource = dtBooks;   
  int intCurrentRows = dgvBooksDetails.Rows.Count;   
  intBooksCounter = intBooksCounter + intCurrentRows;   
  for (int c = intCurrentRows; c < intBooksCounter; c++)  
  {   
    Book objBook = new Book();   
    objBook.ID = BookID[c];   
    objBook.Title = BookTitle[c];  
    objBook.Author = BookAuthor[c];  
    objBook.Genre = BookGenre[c];  
    objBook.Price = Double.Parse(BookPrice[c]);  
    objBook.PublishDate = DateTime.Parse(BookPublish_Date[c]);  
    objBook.Description = BookDescription[c];  
    dtBooks.Rows.Add(objBook.ID, objBook.Title, objBook.Author, objBook.Genre,
                     objBook.Price, objBook.PublishDate, objBook.Description);   
  }
}
```

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: Are you doing some sort of Paging ?

Comment: No, Try to add records of one xml file to other xml file. Can you help me in this regard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line causing trouble is this:

```
int intCurrentRows = dgvBooksDetails.Rows.Count;
```

You take this value as start for your loop. However, the rows collection counts from 0 to `Count-1`, so using `Count` to access a value of the rows collection causes an index out of bounds error.

Another thing: `BookTitle`, `BookAuthor` etc. are also indexed from 0 to `Count-1` (or `Length-1` if they are arrays). I'm not sure from what you've told us, but are you sure that these collections can be accessed by index the way you do? I mean, could it be they only contains the items to be added and thus need to be indexed from 0 to X instead of `number of existing items` to `number of existing items + number of new items` (that's what you do in your code)?

Comment: Well, Count-1 causes an index out of bound only when you are exceeding the size of array/list. But, it my case it is not because I've check in debugging. The point where error occurs have these values of in for loop: for (int c = 9; c < 23; c++). Secondly, BookTitle, BookAuthor are alos list which has no fixed size. And in last items needed to be added are indexed as existing items to (number of existing items+number of new items). Error comes at last line in loop in which I added the all values to a row in DataTable. Can you help me in this regard ??

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding what you say. To make things clearer: In that last loop, what's the value of `c` and what's the value of `BookTitle.Count`? Does the error occur on the `dtBooks.Rows.Add`-line?

Comment: Let me clear the things: Existing Records (Rows) in DataTable are 5. I insert a new file wich contains 15 records(15 new rows). In loop, it started to add rows in DataTable. But,when c=9, and all other list (BookTitle, BookAuthor , etc) have accurate data.... and controls goes to dtBooks.Rows.Add() there comes error.

Comment: OK, let's ask differently: Do `BookTitle`, etc. contain the data for the *new* records only, or do they *also* contain the information about the already added records?

Comment: Thanks Dear, you make me to figure out that. Actaally, BookTitle, etc contains data for new records only so, I shall use the appropriate index to get value from thos list. And I've done that which is fruitfull.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems you have an array *n* long and you are trying to access the *nth* or greater element within it.  Indexes are **0** based and so an *n* sized array must be accessed by indexes *0* to *n-1*.

Comment: Well, **it's not an array of fixed size** but, a **DataTable** and my task is to **add rows in that table after the no of rows which it contain already**. I've debug my code. Detail is: *intCurrentRows=5, intBooksCounter=15*, **It adss 4 to 5 rows in DataTable** and then show the Error. If it was the case as you said, it didn't add any row to DataTable dtBooks.

Comment: Yes but whether its fixed size or not it still surely applies to the current size.  Accessing an element p when the current size is p will still fail since p-1 would be the current highest index.

Comment: What does that comment even mean? "Not fixed size".  It is not a proper sentence, it means nothing to me or anyone else.  And you don;t really provide enough information as every answer everyone posts up you just say no to.

Comment: I think you've asked about the size of lists in your question. If not, then I'm sorry. Don't you ?

Comment: No I said that whether it is fixed size or not that trying to access an index that isnt within the bounds will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your arrays (`BookTitle`, `BookAuthor`, `BookGenre`, `BookPrice`, `BookPublish_Date`,  and `BookDescription`) have the correct length (minimum intBooksCounter).