# Visual Basic 2010 Data Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

This the coding i use ::=

```
          Dim loopX As Integer

             For loopX = 0 To 1000

                If txtID.Text = GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(0).Text And
                    txtPassword.Text <> GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(1).Text Then
                    lblWarnLogin.Text = "please insert the correct password"

                ElseIf txtID.Text <> GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(0).Text And
                    txtPassword.Text <> GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(1).Text Then
                    lblWarnLogin.Text = "please insert the correct id or password"


                ElseIf txtID.Text <> GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(0).Text Or
                    txtPassword.Text <> GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(1).Text Then
                    lblWarnLogin.Text = "please insert the correct id and password"

                ElseIf txtID.Text <> GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(0).Text And
                    txtPassword.Text = GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(1).Text Then
                    lblWarnLogin.Text = "please insert the correct id or password"

                ElseIf txtID.Text = GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(0).Text And
                    txtPassword.Text = GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(1).Text Then
                    Session.Add("idResident", txtID.Text)
                    Response.Redirect("ResidentPage.aspx")
                    NavigateUrl = "~/ResidentPage.aspx"


                Else : lblWarnLogin.Text = "please insert the correct id or password"

                End If

            Next
```

Here the error :

```
Line 24: Else : For loopX = 0 To 1000
Line 25:
Line 26: If txtID.Text = GVResident.Rows(loopX).Cells(0).Text And
Line 27: txtPassword.Text <> Resident.Rows(loopX).Cells(1).Text Then
Line 28: lblWarnLogin.Text = "please insert the correct password"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502745/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-colle)

You need to check  GVResident.Rows.Count > 0 then to do the operation

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you must check index of cells - are they really 0 and 1. In your code it's only one possible source of error.
**P.S.**
I don't know what is source of loopX varibale but your code may count as row  that contain table head, but not DataRow actually.